# StandardScaler Doesn't Scale Properly

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, theano, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to use StandardScaler to scale the features of a neural network.

Lets say then neural network has these features:

```
1.0  2.0   3.0
4.0  5.0   6.0
4.0  11.0  12.0
etc ...
```

When I apply StandardScaler to the whole thing (all rows) I get the following result for the first row:

```
['-0.920854068785', '-0.88080603151', '-0.571888559111']
```

When I try to apply the StandardScaler to the first row only (matrix consisting of just the first row) I get completelly different result.

```
['0.0', '0.0', '0.0']
```

Obviosly the neural network won't work this way, because the rows are not the same. Is there any way to use Standard scaller in a way so I get the same results each time, for the same input(line)?

Here is the code and the output:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np
sc = StandardScaler()

#defining the (big) matrix
AR = np.array([[1.0,2.0,3.0],[4.0,5.0,6.0],[4.0,11.0,12.0],[42.0,131.0,1121.0],[41.0,111.0,121.0]])
AR = sc.fit_transform(AR)
print "fited data from big array:"
m=0
for row in AR: 
    m = m + 1
    if m==1:print [str(m) for m in row]

#defining the (small) matrix
AR1 = np.array([[1.0,2.0,3.0]])
AR1 = sc.fit_transform(AR1)
print "fited data from small array"
for row in AR1: 
     print [str(m) for m in row]
```

The output is:

```
fited data from big array:
['-0.920854068785', '-0.88080603151', '-0.571888559111']
fited data from small array
['0.0', '0.0', '0.0']
```

Comment: From the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html), the input to `fit_transform` is `[n_samples, n_features]`. It's scaling on the columns. There's only one value in each column, hence you get 0.

Comment: Yes, there is only one value on each column. But the result must be the same. Otherwise the input for neural network won't be the same.

Comment: But the results can't be the same because you're fitting to different data. Perhaps you meant to call `fit_transform(AR)` and `transform(AR1)`

Comment: Actually yes, it should be transform instead of fit_transform. But on another data somehow I don't get exactly the same data even when I use transform. But in this example it is ok.

Comment: I will try to isolate the problem since this exampe is huge - around 300 rows or more. And then I will post it.

Comment: Actually this poart is probably ok, because when I isolate the matrix from main program and execute everything is the same as it should. I guess something else is problem but not related to standard scaller.

Comment: Thanks for transform/fit_transform I used it wrongly with labelencoder as well as with onohotencoder.

Comment: Glad to help. Please consider marking the upvoted answer below as correct, since it essentially says the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`StandardScaler` will shift the data by **mean** and scale it by **std**, since you only pass one row to it, mean for each column is the value itself and value will be shifted to zero. See more [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html).

```
>>> sc = StandardScaler()
>>> arr = np.array([[1.0,2.0,3.0]])
>>> sc.fit(arr)

>>> sc.mean_, sc.scale_
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.]), array([ 1.,  1.,  1.]))
```

In your case, you should `fit` the scaler to all the data and for each row, you can use `transform` to get the result.

```
sc.fit(data) # this will compute mean and std on all rows
scaled_row = sc.transform(row) # apply shift to a single row
```

Answer (score 0):

Like StandardScaler all estimators have class variables which can be accessed and the values can be printed.
In case of `StandardScaler` since you want to print the mean you should do something like the following:

- `scaler = StandardScaler()`
- `scaler.fit(my_input_array)`
- `print scaler.mean_ # to get the mean for every column`
- `print scaler.var_ # to get the variance for every column`

you can find the list of all such variables in the [doc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#)

Note: The purpose of StandardScaler is to make your mean `0` and also scale it, and **NOT** to find the mean or variance.

This is done so that your input becomes an ideal one for other functions/algorithms can work and you get a better accuracy.